# What properties of a material make it ideal for acoustic foam or paneling?

Tags: recording, acoustics, homerecording

I want to make some acoustic foam/paneling substitute but I'm wondering makes foam paneling "good" or not? I know that if it's too dense or stiff then the sound won't "trap" and will just bounce right off like it was a wall, and if it's not dense enough (like a soft couch cushion) then it won't trap enough frequency.

What's the proper, industry-standard density or material and most importantly what common materials could I use as a substitute? Could I glue some rugs together and accomplish a similar thing?

Comment: Be worth a look at rehearsal and recording studios. See what they use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of raw materials, Corning 703 insulation panels (which I believe are fiberglass) is very popular. You can't really make a raw material on your own, and you don't really have to shape 703 panels, you just have to cover them with something and mount them correctly. You can do web searches on 703 acoustic panel DIY projects. Here's one hit that I just came up with:

http://buyinsulationproducts.com/build-diy-acoustic-wall-panels.html

In terms of why these materials work the way they do, you pretty much have it when it comes to the density. The density of the material controls the range of frequencies it absorbs, mainly in the midrange. High frequencies are more likely to bounce around so they are often diffused (made to reflect in random directions), and the frequencies that are diffused best is determined by the sizes of the surfaces that a reflecting. Low frequency control is more about pulling energy out of air that is actively moving - usually by creating a resonant space that absorbs energy at the resonant frequency. With a 703 panel install, the distance the panels are away from the walls represents the size of the resonant space and the 703 acts to absorb the energy.

The energy absorbed is converted to heat but the amount of heat energy generated by that conversion is negligible. That does bring to mind an important consideration of room treatments which is that you don't want them to be easily flammable or give off toxic fumes if they are heated or burned. Covering a room with any product makes that product a significant factor in the case of a fire. Using cheap foam products is dangerous in this way. 703 panels are designed for construction and therefore are not prone to combustion or toxic fume release. Other professional sound control products (e.g., Auralex and similar brands) are also designed to have better performance in fire situations compared to, say, packing foam.

**Important Note:** I'm assuming what you are trying to do is control reflections, standing waves, and flutter echoes within a room to make the room sound as good as possible. If your goal is to "soundproof" a room and prevent sound from leaving or coming into a room, that is an entirely different task. In that case, mass and air gaps are important, and the ideal material is gypsum board (AKA sheet rock, wallboard, etc.) that is fastened to wall framing. You might also research Green Glue for controlling sound transmission.

Comment: Another good link for 703 panel construction: http://www.aaronbrownsound.com/571/

Comment: Your "important note" is actually what I was asking about, but your entire answer benefited me greatly!

Comment: Look at Owens-corning 707 insulation- which is a denser version of 703- at 7lbs/ft^3.  It has similar (actually, better, according to the datasheet) acoustical properties to 703.  It also has about the same density as a plank of balsa wood.  It should be clear that hanging balsa wood planks on your wall will not work nearly as well in the studio!  There's much more at play than density.